# Howto: Avatar for Mattermost in Jenkins on Project Basis

Tags: jenkins, mattermost

We use the Mattermost Plugin for Jenkins.
When the Pipelinebuild has finished in Jenkins it shall send a message to the hook in mattermost reporting the status of the build.
Can I assign an avatar on per project basis like

```
    failure {
        mattermostSend color: 'danger', message: 'API-Tests have failed', channel: 'api-tests', avatar: 'http://someadress.com/avatar.jpg'
    }
```

?

What format must the icon have? size and extension?

Answer (score 0):

### Quick answer

You can specify the avatar by using the `icon` parameter, as such:

```
mattermostSend channel: 'api-tests', color: 'danger',
    message: 'API-Tests have failed',
    icon: 'http://someadress.com/avatar.jpg'
```

### Avatar limitations

I am unaware of limitations to the avatar. As long as it's an image with a reasonable extension, it should work. I use some official logo's of products (Puppet, Jenkins, Git, Docker) to decorate the bots reporting for those products. The avatars seem to be automatically scaled to fit.

### Use the Pipeline Syntax Snippet

In case you did not know this, you can use the "Pipeline Syntax Snippet Generator" inside your Jenkins. To use this, go to any build or any folder and find the link in the top left pane ("Pipeline Syntax").

You can then select a step (eg. `mattermostSend`), see the default parameters and open the advanced parameters. Now you can enter values in the text fields (including the "Custom icon") and click "Generate Pipeline Script".